# Magento 2 Logo not showing in the front end

Tags: magento2

I have setup fresh magento 2 app on local. When i update the logo it's not reflecting on homepage .. when uploading the log it automatically create website folder and placed the logo inside that folder. It has to uploaded on logo folder .. Is there anyone have an idea about this issue

Comment: you logo size and format?

Comment: Its a png with 250*50px

Comment: so let me know exact Magento version, is there any other theme installed?

Comment: if possible share URL too.

Comment: Its magento 2.3 
websites/1/logoNew.png

Comment: 2.3.0/2.3.1 or else?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel 2.3.3

Comment: please see the answer if still not works then tell me ok

Comment: Can u please check may be permission issue would be there.

Comment: @DevSpace hey you did that?

Comment: Try to clear the Magento cache

Answer (score 1):

please do one step clear cache. if Linux system then

```
sudo php bin/magento c:c
```

if windows system

```
php bin/magento c:c
```

Or you just clear cache from admin => System => Tools =>Cache Management. and flush it.
Hope it works!